# Changing a string to an integer

Tags: java, string, validation, integer

When I run the client and enter a number it is passed as a string. However it must be passed as an integer. How do I change this? and also change from while(true) to a do while so when the user enters "*" the program ends.

```
   while (true){
                   System.out.print("Enter a number ");
           String message = keyboard.nextLine(); 
           out.writeUTF(message); 
       }
```

Comment: What is `keyboard` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java

Answer (score 0):

use `int option = keyboard.nextInt();`

seen here : [if you want to know more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Comment: what do i change this line to?     out.writeUTF(message);

Comment: @JanetKeelan what are you trying to say?

Comment: I got it sorted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
`Scanner.nextInt()` is giving back an integer...

Example

```
    final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = 0;
    while(true){
            System.out.print("Enter a number ");
            number = in.nextInt();
            out.writeUTF(number);
    }
```

## UPDATE:

if you need to do this in a loop until the user enter a specific key (e.g. "*")
then:

```
final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = "";
do {
    System.out.print("Enter a number ");
    int numberParsed = 0;
    input = in.nextLine();
    try {
        numberParsed = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.println(numberParsed);
        out.writeUTF(numberParsed);
    } catch (final NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.err.println("That input could not be parsed to integer....");
    }
} while (!input.equals("*"));
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Is it possible to change this into a do while now so that when a user enters "*" the program stops running?

Comment: yes, for sure, but the code must change a little... take a look at the update please

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that keyboard is an object of type `Scanner`.

The `Scanner` has a method [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) to retrieve the next integer.

Otherwise you can convert a string to an integer using the method [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) as follow:

```
String message = keyboard.nextLine(); 
int myInt = Integer.parseInt(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `nextLine` and `writeUTF`, I would use `nextInt` (and `hasNextInt` allowing you terminate input with a non-`int`) with `writeInt`. Using a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and a `ByteArrayOutputStream` for testing, that might look something like

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(baos)) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number ");
    while (keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
        int v = keyboard.nextInt();
        out.writeInt(v);
        System.out.print("Enter a number ");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(baos.toByteArray()));
```